# React-Native fetch post with encodeURIComponent value

Tags: react-native

I am going to use fetch to post

```
const token = 'ABCD123:A'
await fetch(path, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   body: token=encodeURIComponent(token),
});
```

encodeURIComponent(token) should be `ABCD123%3AA`

My server should get encoded value, decode value and then store to DB.
But in my api server, it gets non-encode body: `token=ABCD123:A`

Should server gets encoded value?

And I have tested same encoded value on Postman, my server is getting encoded value.

As my server gets different value, is it Fetch API problem or my fetch request issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to make `Object` for Body,

```
const token = 'ABCD123:A'
await fetch(path, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   body: {
           'token':encodeURIComponent(token)
         }

});
```

Comment: And if that also does not work then encode outside fetch and log that value, see if it is getting encoded or not?

Comment: I have logged the value before passing to fetch, which is encoded.
But server is getting non-encoded.

Comment: if I pass object into body, it throws `unsupported BodyInit type` error...

Comment: 'Content-Type': 'application/json', you can change this to send objects